# How to apply Render Transform to mouse position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm making a ploting application. Because I want same behaviour as math plots I apply following transformation to canvas with data points:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <TransformGroup x:Key="CanvasTransform">
        <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="30"/>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
    </TransformGroup>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Here is the transformation used:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas>
                <Canvas.RenderTransformOrigin>
                    <Point X="0.5" Y="0.5"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransformOrigin>
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource CanvasTransform}"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
             </Canvas>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

So far so good. The problem is with adding points to plot. Because the mouse click event is returning position in window coordinates it's no use. The point is added at wrong location, because it's transformed after adding.

e.g. Canvas is 400 units high. I click in top left corner mouse location is `[X=10, Y=10]` this point is added to the plot and rendered. The render transform then use the [10,10] point and calculates it's new position: `[X=40,Y=360]` (window coordinates).

It means that I click in top corner and the point appears in bottom corner. Which is in fact correct behavior.

My question is, how to apply the render transform manually before storing the point, so the point will appear under mouse.

So far I have tried following:

```
var trans = Resources["CanvasTransform"] as TransformGroup;
var mouse = e.GetPosition(this); // mouse position relative to canvas
var newPoint = trans.Transform(mouse);
```

But after this transformation `newPoint` has following coordinates `[40,-39]`. Again I know why is the result as it is. The origin of the transform is `[0,0]` and the translation is `29` probably due to rounding error.

Now I can take this new point and manualy change the values - subtract `30` from X coord and then add `Canvas.ActualHeight` to Y coordinate, which will fix the position.

But then what's the point?

My question is: is it possible to apply the `RenderTransform` in same fashion as the rendere is doing it, to avoid fiddling with coordinates manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"` in `ScaleTransform` is unnecessary. All it does is adds a tiny translate transform (half-pixel).
2. To get source position from transformed position, you need to use inverse transformation (`Inverse` property of `Transform`). This is where `X-30` error comes from.
3. To change transformation origin, you need to, first, subtract half canvas size, then transform, then add half canvas size.

   ```
   var origin = new Point(lstItems.ActualWidth / 2, lstItems.ActualHeight / 2);
   var transform = ((TransformGroup)Resources["CanvasTransform"]).Clone();
   transform.Children.Insert(0, new TranslateTransform(-origin.X, -origin.Y));
   transform.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(origin.X, origin.Y));
   _transform = transform.Inverse;
   ```

Complete sample:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="So21501609WpfMouseRenderTransform.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Control.Resources>
        <TransformGroup x:Key="CanvasTransform">
            <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="30"/>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
        </TransformGroup>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </Control.Resources>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="lstItems" MouseDown="LstItems_OnMouseDown" Width="400" Height="400" Background="Transparent">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Canvas.RenderTransformOrigin>
                        <Point X="0.5" Y="0.5"/>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransformOrigin>
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource CanvasTransform}"/>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Text="10 10"/>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="300" Text="10 300"/>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300" Text="300 300"/>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="10" Text="300 10"/>
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace So21501609WpfMouseRenderTransform
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private GeneralTransform _transform;

        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            var origin = new Point(lstItems.ActualWidth / 2, lstItems.ActualHeight / 2);
            var transform = ((TransformGroup)Resources["CanvasTransform"]).Clone();
            transform.Children.Insert(0, new TranslateTransform(-origin.X, -origin.Y));
            transform.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(origin.X, origin.Y));
            _transform = transform.Inverse;
        }

        private void LstItems_OnMouseDown (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point pos = _transform.Transform(e.GetPosition(lstItems));

            var item = new TextBlock { Text = pos.ToString() };
            Canvas.SetLeft(item, pos.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(item, pos.Y);
            lstItems.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```